# How do I get rid of "The formula uses a Boolean in place of a number"?

Tags: numbers, iwork

I'm using a formula to convert stone and lbs to lbs only.  Here is the formula that I am using:

```
INT(B13)×14+IF(INT(B13)≠B13,(B13−INT(B13))×10^(LEN(B13)−FIND(".",B13)))
```

My stone and lbs are written in this format:  12.2, which would equal 12 stones and 2 lbs.

With this formula I get the blue flag and the message:

> The formula uses a Boolean in place of a number

Is there anyway I can correct my formula and get rid of the blue flag?  It calculates everything, it's just this blue flag makes it look unprofessional.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know where to begin doing that.   I just copied this formula from another post I found online.  Unfortunately it hasn't really worked out as well as I hoped it would.

Comment: What exactly is in b13 andi4

Comment: The cells in stone format can't be numeric if you're doing that; 2.1 and 2.10 are encoded the same if they're numeric, but one is 29 lbs and the other is 38 lbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you get that warning message when the input to the formula, i.e.  the weight in stone and lbs, is an integer such as 12 instead of, for example, "12.2".

This would happen because the IF() function in the formula you posted returns the logical value of FALSE to the formula if the weight is an integer. To fix this, use the following formula, for example, instead:

```
INT(B13) × 14 + IF( INT(B13)≠B13, (B13 − INT(B13)) × 10^(LEN(B13) − FIND(".", B13)), 0 )
```

You can paste and use the formula exactly as shown above. The fix is the ", 0" added towards the end. A few spaces are added to the formula only to improve its readability; they would not affect how it actually works.

Comment: However the first issue is why is a number in a field that is a string - ie using FIND on a numeric is just wrong

Comment: @mmmmmm In this case, it is not wrong because, as described in the OP, the original weights such as 12.2 are not conventional numbers: the period in the original weights are separators rather than conventional decimal points. So, even though one stone is 14 lbs, one can not simply multiply the 12.2 with 14 to convert it to lbs given such defined original weights. The correct operation is 12*14 + 2 = 170. The FIND() on the original weight helps separate the lbs part of the original weight from the stone part and then the lbs part is processed accordingly.